# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\vert a_n\sin(nx)\vert$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert a_n\vert<\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\vert a_n\sin(nx)\vert$
converges for all $x$ in a set of positive measure $A$. I'm trying to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert a_n\vert<\infty$.

The only useful result I can recall of periodic functions is the that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $T$ then  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g(nx)dx=\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx \bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{T} \int_0^Tg(x)dx\bigg)$. I don't claim this is the best way to go. But if we let $g(x)=\sin x$, then $T=2\pi$. I am not sure what I should define $f$ as since it is required to be in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but if I had a decent $f$ my idea is to write $A\subset\bigcup_{k=N}^M[k,k+1]$ then show $\int_{l}^{l+1}\sum\vert a_n \vert<\infty$ for any $l\in [N,M-1]$. Another potential problem is that with my choice of $g$, $1/T\int_0^Tg=1/2\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\sin=0$.

Am I anywhere near showing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\vert a_n\vert<\infty$?

Comment: I think your last $2\pi$ should be in curly brackets? Also, if $(2k+1)\pi/2 \in A$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, then it's quite easy isn't it?

Comment: I'd rather go for proving that $\int_A |\sin(nx)|{\rm d}x > \delta$ for all $n\geq 1$ and some $\delta$ depending only on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n \sin(nx)|$. By assumption $f$ is finite a.s. on the set $A$ of positive measure. Thus $A = \cup_{n=1}^\infty  (A\cap \{|f|\leq n\}) \cup N$ where $N$ has measure zero. In particular we may choose $n$ such that $B:= A \cap \{|f|<n\}$ has (necessarily finite) strictly positive measure.

Then consider
$$
\infty > \lambda(B)n \geq \int_B f(x)dx = \int_B \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k \sin(kx)|dx
$$
$$
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|\int_B |\sin(kx)|dx \geq\inf_k\int_B|\sin(kx)|dx\cdot\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|
$$
so the conclusion will follow if we can show the infimum is strictly positive.
If the infimum were zero, we could chose a strictly increasing sequence $k_n\to \infty$ where we have $L^1(B)$ convergence of $\sin(k_n x)$ to $0$, and hence a subsequence on which $\sin(k_nx) \to 0$ almost everywhere in $B$. However, $\limsup \sin(k_n x) =1$ a.e. (e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=mnY8LpyXHM0C&pg=PA32) shows $(k_n x)$ will be a.s. uniformly distributed mod $1$) so this is not the case. Thus the result is proved.